Why is a dynamic picklist query in my Custom LWC component executing twice when added to App Builder and click save?
I have a Custom LWC component exposed on a Record Detail page in Salesforce. This component includes a Design attribute that dynamically queries picklist values. When I drag and drop this component onto an App Builder page and click save.After clicking save, a user log is generated showing that the dynamic picklist query is executed twice. I'm uncertain about the reason behind this double execution of the query when click save.
Debug Log screenshot for query execution
Builder page screenshot
Dynamic picklist value dropdown
JS Code:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ListView extends LightningElement {

    @api AccountName;
   
}

Html code:
<template>
    test
</template>

XML File code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <masterLabel>List View</masterLabel>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage,lightning__AppPage,lightning__UtilityBar">
            <property 
                name="AccountName" 
                default="" 
                required="true" 
                type="String" 
                datasource="apex://AccountNamePicklist" 
                description="Name of the List view configuration. This value is required." 
                label="Configuration Name"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Apex Class code:
public with sharing class AccountNamePicklist extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {
    List<Account> AccountList = new List<Account>();
    
    public AccountNamePicklist() {        
        System.debug('enter Method');
        /*---------------------- This query executed Two times ---------------------*/
        AccountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 2000];
    }
     
    public override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue() {
        VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('', '');
        if (AccountList.size() > 0) {
            defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow(AccountList[0].Name, AccountList[0].Name); 
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
    
    public override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows AccountNameList = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        for (Account acc : AccountList) {
            VisualEditor.DataRow value = new VisualEditor.DataRow(acc.Name, acc.Name);  
            AccountNameList.addRow(value);  
        }
        return AccountNameList;
    }
}
}


The Salesforce docs show this text:

The VisualEditor.DynamicPickList method isValid() runs in Experience
Cloud sites when the page loads. If you don’t override the method in
your custom Apex class that extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList, the
default implementation executes getValues() at runtime, which can
cause performance degradations. To improve performance, implement a
non-operational isValid()

This would cause the getValues() method to be executed more than once as it is also used to check if the value chosen is a valid value, it could also mean that the class is instantiated twice.
to avoid this behaviour you can override the isValid() function and do the query only if you require the accounts:
public override Boolean isValid(Object attributeValue) {
   return true;
}

also remove the constructor doing the query and replace the accountList with this:
List<Account> accountList {
    get {
        if (accountList == null) {
            initAccountList();
        }
        return accountList;
    }
    set;
}

private static List<Account> initAccountList() {
    this.accountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 2000];
}

method.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm
